# Azure Arm template - app setting missing after appservice resource successfully provisioned

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

I am currently provisioning a new resource group using Azure Arm template and Powershell

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment

The resource group template defines all the resources.

A couple of different app service resources are provisioned as part of this resource group. Each app service resource has app settings.

The resource group gets provisioned sucessfully including its app service but from time to time, the app settings are missing on the newly provisioned app service. I am required to teardown and re-create the resource group and it works fine.

When the custom app settings are missing then, in the portal, there is only one app setting visible: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION

Any pointers for how I can troubleshoot this so the environment provisioning process is consistent?

Comment: Would mind sharing the template code you are using?

Comment: @TomSun the template is for a resource group so I will have to check how much I can trim down before I can share it here. 
Further info - I am using New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment to provision resource in this template.
I have notice similar behavior when using Slots. The slots are added as a child resource of the website resource.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the -DeploymentDebugLogLevel parameter in the PowerShell command you are using for the deployment?  There are different values for that parameter that control how much debugging information you get.  I have used it in the past to help troubleshoot IaaS deployments using ARM templates.  More information is here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/debugging-arm-template-deployments/

Comment: I have used this in the past and will enable this again to get latest details, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the app have slots? If yes, are the appsettings tied to specific slots? When we perform a swap slot, then the appsettings can disappear, if the settings are slot specific. Also, are you performing an Incremental upgrade or Complete? As Tom commented, sharing the template will help in understanding whats going on.

Comment: This happens at the time of resource provisioning and I have seen it with and without slots. Its a complete new resource provisioning. The resources are deleted when not in use, we provision them again as and when needed